# Windows user trying install Git on Solaris

Tags: git, solaris

Is there simply way to install Git on Solaris as on Windows without installing any side libraries and compiling source files? And if not, why?

UPD. Yes I'm looking for single package that will be easy to install.

We have ~8 solaris zones using for development those we need simple way to install git fast on they. Installation should be easy because each member of team possibly will be do it and it should be fast because of big count of zones.

Comment: Are you looking for a single package that includes everything, or do you want to aviod installing those libraries that git depends on completly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried it, but it sounds like the easiest way is to [install pkg-get](http://www.opencsw.org/get-it/pkg-get/)

```
# pkgadd -d http://mirror.opencsw.org/opencsw/pkg_get.pkg
```

Then run

```
# pkg-get install git
```

Comment: It helped. 
But it installed everything but the kitchen sink and asked every time should it continue or no (maybe 15 times)